# Opera GX occasionally puts small banner ads in new tabs. How do I disable this?

Tags: opera

In Opera GX, there are sometimes ads on the new tab page.  They are easy enough to dismiss with a `X` button in the top corner.  This is not adware, they are Opera GX themed and clearly intentional.

I would rather they never showed up at all.

**Is it possible to disable this feature?  If so, how?**

I've tried searching the advanced settings, but did not find a way.

(note: the next time one pops up, I'll take a screenshot)

Comment: Ask yourself.. "How does Opera make money?" and "How can they make money if you switch search engines and allow you to disable Opera hosted ads?".  Opera is NOT FREE.  It just appears to be on the surface.

Comment: I suspected as much, but it's still nice to have a well indexed Q&A or perhaps a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera has made it almost impossible to change the New Tab page, on purpose,
since ads is what keeps them alive.

It might be possible still in Opera, but not in GX.

See [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/operabrowser/comments/nm12vj/comment/htgq4cm/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
for a method that requires installing two extensions :
[Infinity new tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/infinity-new-tab/dbfmnekepjoapopniengjbcpnbljalfg/)
and
[New Tab Start Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-start-page/mjfahldkpjhcnfbbmdhpjolcjpcfhcpj)
and setting in the New Tab Start Page's settings the custom URL to
`chrome-extension://dbfmnekepjoapopniengjbcpnbljalfg/newtab/index.html`.

Note that such workarounds can stop working without notice,
and also that adding two extensions might be more risky than permitting
the ads in the first place.